# Can't use both Fabulous and Android.Speech

Tags: android, f#

I have created a Fabulous SqueakyApp following instructions on https://fsprojects.github.io/Fabulous/Fabulous.XamarinForms/

I would like to update this app to access the Android.Speech library to respond to commands such as "Up", "Down".  I have successfully created a mini voice-activated app elsewhere using a blank Android app.

However, I can't find any way to reference Android.Speech or anything in the Android namespace from within a Fabulous project.  I assume that this is in some way a consequence of alternative UI rendering classes, but is there something I can do to get access to Android.Speech?

Comment: You say you created a Xamarin.Forms app and presumably Fabulous lives in the Xamarin.Forms netstandard project, and Android has its own project. So how could you expect to find Android namespaces in the Xamarin.Forms project?

Comment: That is where my confusion lay - I need two projects.  When creating a blank xamarin app in VS the Android namepsace is available, and it was not obvious to me that Fabulous should behave differently.

Comment: Hint: https://github.com/dev-aritra/XFSpeech